# Calling sequence of the methods postProcessBeforeInitialization(), init() and postProcessAfterInitialization() methods in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, sequence, init

I am using Spring DI version 4.2. 
My "applicationContext.xml" content is as  below.

```
   <bean id="bObj1" class="com.springExample.B" scope="prototype" init-method="init" destroy-method="destory" />
```

Below is my Class "com.springExample.B"

```
public class B  implements BeanPostProcessor {


public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method postProcessBeforeInitialization()");
    return bean;
}

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method postProcessAfterInitialization()");
    return bean;
}

public void init() {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method init()");
}

public void m3() {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method m3()");

}   

public void destory() {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method  destory()");
}
```

}

I have read the calling sequence of life cycle methods as follows.

1. postProcessBeforeInitialization()
2. init()
3. postProcessAfterInitialization()

I am creating the spring container and calling Bean as follows

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");    
B b = ac.getBean("bObj1", B.class);
b.m3();
```

I have written SOP statements in all methods of Class "com.springExample.B". when I ran the code I am getting output as below.

```
In class B, Method init()
In class B, Method postProcessBeforeInitialization()
In class B, Method init()
In class B, Method postProcessAfterInitialization()
In class B, Method m3()
```

**I Could not understand why init() method is called before postProcessBeforeInitialization()?**

Comment: Can you please show your B class in question

Comment: @sForSujit  -  Added Class B in my question.

Answer (score 0):

When Implemented separate class for BeanPostProcessor.
Its working as expected.  
Below are updated class and new class.

```
public class B  {

public void init() {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method init()");
}

public void m3() {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method m3()");
}

public void destory() {
    System.out.println("In class B, Method  destory()");
}
}
```

BeanPostProcessorImpl class

```
public class BeanPostProcessorImpl implements BeanPostProcessor {

public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("In class BeanPostProcessorImpl, Method postProcessBeforeInitialization()");
    return bean;
}

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("In class BeanPostProcessorImpl, Method postProcessAfterInitialization()");
    return bean;
}
}
```